# MGTwitterEngine: GetBulkUserInformationFor:

Tags: iphone, twitter, mgtwitterengine

I'm using MGTwitterEngine to grab profiles from an NSString but I only get the first response in the list. Changing the method in MGTwitterEngine.m to use screen_name instead of user_id gives me a 404 error, using user_id works, but it only returns the first in the list.

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"users/lookup.%@?screen_name=%@", API_FORMAT, userIDs];
```

MGTwitterEngine.m

```
- (NSString *)getBulkUserInformationFor:(NSString *)userIDs{

if (!userIDs) {
    return nil;
    }

NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"users/lookup.%@?user_id=%@", API_FORMAT, userIDs];
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:0];

return [self _sendRequestWithMethod:nil path:path queryParameters:params body:nil requestType:MGTwitterBulkUserInformationRequest responseType:MGTwitterUsers];}
enter code here
```

My method:

```
- (void)userInfoReceived:(NSArray *)userInfo forRequest:(NSString *)connectionIdentifier {

    for(NSDictionary *d in userInfo) {
    NSLog(@"dee: %@", d);}
```

.. and my call:

```
[_engine getBulkUserInformationFor:@"14483463,25552002,1540791,307428962,61605222"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like a similiar problem to this issue on the github page for mgtwitterengine:

https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine/issues/58

change

```
#define TWITTER_DOMAIN @"twitter.com"
```

to

```
#define TWITTER_DOMAIN @"api.twitter.com/1"
```

in MGTwitterEngine.m